# Why was the keyword argument 'encoding' removed from json.loads() in Python 3.9?

Tags: json, python-3.x

The official docs of the json package state:

> json.loads(s, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)¶
>
> > Changed in version 3.6: s can now be of type bytes or bytearray. The input encoding should be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.

> > Changed in version 3.9: The keyword argument encoding has been removed.

What was the purpose of the 'encoding' keyword prior to Python 3.9? Why was the encoding keyword removed? Is json.loads() (3.9+) capable of automatically detecting bytes and bytearray input encoding from UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32?

**Reference**: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: (https://docs.python.org/release/3.9.0/whatsnew/changelog.html#changelog)   [bpo-39377](https://bugs.python.org/issue39377): Removed encoding option from json.loads(). It has been **deprecated since Python 3.1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is json.loads() (3.9+) capable of automatically detecting bytes and bytearray input encoding from UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32?

Yes -- if you look at the json package [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12d0a7642fc552fa17b1608fe135306cddec5f4e/Lib/json/__init__.py#L341), `json.loads()` calls `detect_encoding()`, which, appropriately, detects input encoding. Check out the code for `detect_encoding()` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12d0a7642fc552fa17b1608fe135306cddec5f4e/Lib/json/__init__.py#L244).